# How to pair items from a nested vector with corresponding single values in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, zipmap

I'm learning Clojure, and want to understand more about sequences. I have a real-life problem which I have reduced to a general one, but I don't know if it has a canonical name. Hopefully the example below makes it clear.

Say I have two vectors, `src` and `dst`. The items in the `src` vector are themselves vectors, and I need to map each item in each vector into the corresponding value in `dst`.

```
(def src [ ["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"] ])
(def dst [ "a" "b" "c" ])
```

I want to produce the following map:

```
{ :a1 "a", :a2 "a", :a3 "a", :b1 "b", :b2 "b", :c1 "c", :c2 "c", :c3 "c", :c4 "c" }
```

I can do this just fine in Python, but the Clojure way of doing it is not clear to me. For this problem, I could just construct a map, but I want to be able to do it in a generic way, not just for this instance.

In Python, this would be:

```
src = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
dst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = {}
for (s, d) in zip(src, dst):
    for x in s:
        result[x] = d
```

In Clojure, I've tried starting with:

```
(interleave src dst)
;=> (["a1" "a2"] "a" ["b1" "b2" "b3"] "b" ["c1"] "c")
```

So I've flattened the vectors, but I don't know how to iterate over the map keys, and pick the values.

Also, `zipmap` doesn't get me too far by itself:

```
(zipmap src (map keyword dst))
;=> {["c1"] :c, ["b1" "b2" "b3"] :b, ["a1" "a2"] :a}
;bogus result
```

Now I would need to flip the map keys and values, and still iterate.

I haven't been successful in constructing a `for` expression either:

```
(for [s src] (zipmap s dst)))
;=> ({"a2" "b", "a1" "a"} {"b3" "c", "b2" "b", "b1" "a"} {"c1" "a"})
;bogus result
```

I'm approaching the problem as pairing two vectors, but I can't seem to get the vectors from the `src` vector into position so that I could just simply `zipmap` each of them with `dst`.

I suspect the answer is really obvious, but my brain is still not working functionally enough. Maybe there is an `into {}` and/or `assoc` in there somewhere.

Any pointers? If you're interested, the real-life problem I mentioned is mapping from RNA codons to amino acids.

Comment: After a long deliberation I have accepted the answer by @xsc, since it is the most instructive. I learned a lot from the gradual approach. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` can take multiple seqs to iterate over, e.g.:

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
;; => (5 7 9)
```

So, this would be the way to get the values you want to process into the same function, resulting in processing of the pairs `["a1" "a2" "a3"]`/`"a"`, etc...

```
(map
  (fn [src dst]
    ???)
  [["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"]]
  ["a" "b" "c"])
```

`zipmap` takes a seq of keys (which we have) and a seq of values (which we have to construct from a single value). `repeat` can be used to create an infinite lazy seq based on a constant value:

```
(take 3 (repeat "a"))
;; => ("a" "a" "a")
```

And:

```
(zipmap ["a1" "a2" "a3"] (repeat "a"))
;; => {"a3" "a", "a2" "a", "a1" "a"}
```

This makes the original code look like this:

```
(map
  (fn [src dst]
    (zipmap src (repeat dst)))
  [["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"]]
  ["a" "b" "c"])
;; => ({"a3" "a", "a2" "a", "a1" "a"} {"b2" "b", "b1" "b"} {"c4" "c", "c3" "c", "c2" "c", "c1" "c"})
```

And finally, you can merge all of these maps into a single one using `into`, resulting in this final piece of code:

```
(into {} (map #(zipmap %1 (repeat %2)) src dst))
;; => {"a3" "a", "c2" "c", "c3" "c", "a1" "a", "b2" "b", "c4" "c", "a2" "a", "c1" "c", "b1" "b"}
```

Comment: This was easy to follow, thanks. I didn't include the map keywording in my original example, but here it would be just a matter of replacing %1 with "(map keyword %1)".

Answer (score 2):

```
user> (into {}
            (for [[sources, dest] (map list src dst),
                  source sources]
                 [(keyword source), dest]))
{:a2 "a", :b2 "b", :c3 "c", :a3 "a", :a1 "a", :b1 "b", :c4 "c", :c2 "c", :c1 "c"}
```

The `for` comprehension creates every source / dest pair, and then `into` is used to populate a hash map from those pairs.

Comment: Well, I didn't realize you could use an inner vector inside a for like that, much as in my Python solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was aiming for the most direct idiomatic translation of the python code.

Answer (score 1):

```
(into {} (mapcat (fn [ss d] (map #(vector (keyword %) d) ss)) src dst))

;{:a3 "a", :c1 "c", :c2 "c", :b2 "b",
; :b1 "b", :c4 "c", :c3 "c", :a2 "a", :a1 "a"}
```

... but I prefer [@noisesmith's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571049/1562315) - `for` is better here.

Comment: Why do you think `for` is better? Performance? Clarity? Style?